# Multiple stems (%) in a Makefile prerequisite

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to use the following Makefile to create the target `foo.a` with `foo.foo.b` as a prerequisite, using the stem character (`%`) as shown.

```
%.a: %.%.b
    touch $@
```

However running `touch foo.foo.b; make foo.a` doesn't work with `No rule to make target`. The debug output below shows that the stem `%` is only expanded once. How to get the desired behavior of replacing all `%` in the prerequisite?

```
Considering target file 'sdf.a'.
 File 'sdf.a' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'sdf.a'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite 'sdf.%.b'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'sdf.%.b'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
  Trying pattern rule with stem 'sdf.%.b'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite 'sdf.%.b,v'.
  (..)
 No implicit rule found for 'sdf.a'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'sdf.a'.
Must remake target 'sdf.a'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'sdf.a'.  Stop.
```

Side note: this seems like a trivial question but for some reason I can't find the answer, maybe I'm using the wrong search terms or overlooking something simple, sorry if that is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stem is only replaced once. If you wish to have stem contents inserted more than once, you would need to use [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.a: $$*.$$*.b
        echo Making $@ from $<
```

Output:

```
$ touch foo.foo.b
$ make -s foo.a
Making foo.a from foo.foo.b
```